# App incompatible for device Samsung SM-G350E 4.4.2

Tags: android

I have simply these permission in my manifest file  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

I have searched but could not find any solution. What might be the reasons?

Comment: is because minSdk() > deviceSdk() ?

Answer (score 0):

You want permissions for GPS sensor, but this phone doesn't have one.

[Official SAMSUNG's phone specification](http://www.samsung.com/africa_en/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/others/SM-G350EZKAXFA)

[Phone specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_star_2_plus-6391.php)